# How is the daily score cap calculated if a downvote occurs after max?

Tags: support, daily-reputation-limit, score

I hit my score cap for the day with a couple of upvotes going unscored, which is what I would expect. However, I then had somebody downvote an answer of mine, which dropped my total score by -2.

Should my upvote "surplus" keep me from losing the two points, or is it (as it seems) strictly chronological? As in, I will have to get another upvote to regain the -2?

Either way, is this a bug or a feature?

**UPDATE**

It does appear to be running in chronological order. When I perform a manual recalc (as suggest by @ConradFrix), my daily does not change, and even the rescore seems to count scores in the order that they happened. Notice the 6, followed by 0's, and then the -2...instead of the 6 becoming a 10 and the following one becoming 6.

```
 2   9740571 [6]
 2   9738649 [0]
 2   9742556 [0]
 3   9742816 [-2]
 3   9742816 [-2]
 3   9742816 [-2]
 3   9742816 [-2]
 3   9742816 [-2]
```

However, I still would like to hear back from a moderator or maybe documentation that denotes this? Otherwise, I am still not sure if this is a bug or purposeful design. If purposeful design, what is the reasoning?

Comment: Out of curiosity what happens when you trigger a manual recalc  at http://stackoverflow.com/reputation

Comment: I deleted the -2 answer and regained my points. I will see if I can reproduce this...hopefully I dont get hit by tons of downvotes :-p. I will let you know shortly

Comment: I just updated my question. This did not work, and only proved the fact...so I am still waiting to hear if this is a bug or on purpose. I personally think it is a bug...but that is me :)

Comment: So did you trigger a manual recalc?

Comment: Yes, the info is below the UPDATE in my question

Comment: @ConradFrix Oy, I will have to double check this tomorrow. When you said trigger...I did not realize you meant the button at the bottom that I totally missed. I had never used that page before. I went to re-verify my test and got yelled at for only one recalc a day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you do need to receive another upvote to "re-reach" the reputation cap for the day. And yes, that's a by-design feature.

As for whether the system *should* be designed to care about chronology, that's a separate question. I think it's actually been asked here on Meta at some point, but I don't know where at the moment.

Comment: Yah, I tried to find any previous questions, but could not. Normally, I would not re-ask the same question, but you are right, my original question was how. So, I will re-ask with a should :)