# Allow "over the cap" votes to offset reputation loss for user removals

Tags: feature-request, reputation

When users get removed, the reputation points due to their votes are removed from the system, and the voting points are subtracted from the current day's reputation. This makes perfect sense.

However, since the points subtracted today have been added at some earlier time, it would make sense to let today's over-the-cap votes to offset the "User was removed" un-votes. Otherwise, the timing of the removal plays into the calculation, which is arbitrary.

Ideally, the process should take into account the entire set of votes on the day the removed vote has been counted: if that day contains a matching over-the-cap vote, the removed vote should not be subtracted at all.

[image: Illustration of the problem.]

**EDIT :** It looks like the the reputation does not get restored even with events that come after the user removal: the removal from 4 hours ago does not get reversed with upvotes from two minutes ago (see below).

[image: Updated illustration]

Comment: You may be interested in this discussion as well: [Don't throw away all votes when a user is deleted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125740/dont-throw-away-all-votes-when-a-user-is-deleted).  Not everyone is in agreement that this reputation loss makes sense =)  Also, the very interesting details about reputation events are here: [What does SE use to calculate reputation?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126922/what-does-se-use-to-calculate-reputations-sql-aggregate-functions-a-manual-met/126942#126942)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## No.

You're not actually losing the reputation *today*. You're losing it on the **day that reputation was actually earned**. It's only *listed* under today to indicate to you *why* you lost the reputation. If on the day you earned that reputation you hit the reputation cap, then the reputation for that day is recalculated to reflect the deleted content (or in this case, retracted votes).

If you uncheck the "show removed posts" box at the bottom of the page, you'll see that for the day you are still sitting at the reputation cap **for today**. That's exactly how the system should work.

[status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

Comment: I guess it's a display issue then. It would be nice to see some reference to the date on which the vote that got retracted was posted originally.

Comment: "If on the day you earned that reputation you hit the reputation cap, then the reputation for that day is recalculated to reflect the deleted content (or in this case, retracted votes)." -- does this mean that if I did hit the cap on a day when the retracted vote has been cast, **and** there was at least one over-the-cap vote on that day, the reputation is not going to change, and the info about the "User was removed" line item would not appear at all?

Comment: No, the line will still appear, but the over-the-cap vote from that day will be recalculated to add reputation instead of being a +0. So your reputation overall wouldn't change, the line would just appear. I agree it can be confusing, but that's why they added that checkbox at the bottom, so you can view it without deletions and retractions.

Comment: @animuson is that checkbox also present on the mobile version of the website? Because not only I see all the -10 listed in my daily rep, but I don't see the current total rep for the day (on my smartphone). So I have to count manually all the +10, subtract the -10, to know where I am at...

Comment: @VonC: I'm not sure. If it's not, you can always request it in a [meta-tag:feature-request].

Comment: @animuson Could you clarify what is going on [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTZrf.png)? The removal came before I hit 200 and the checkbox has no visible change showing me I have hit 200 today. [SFF profile link for reference](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/58193/thelethalcarrot?tab=reputation).